# Entering text-data into a Table cell, without having a UITextField in each cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to let the user fill in some data to be submitted.

So I have a table with 7 cells, each of them are labeled so they know what data goes into the field.
I though about putting a UITextField in each cell, but it looks like its out of place and the user can enter up to 255 chars, so also it doesn't display the data so nicely.

Can anybody recommend a good way to handle this kind of thing, whats the best solution in your experience?

Maybe hiding the UITextField after they are done entering data and display the data in some other manner?

Kind Regards,
-Code

Comment: Is the table going to be displaying whatever the user  types in? If so then how can you _not_ have a text field in there?

Comment: If you're not looking for customization, I think you should use only what you need, which is seven UITextFields and maybe in another view, show the data to the user that he has typed with confirmation UIButton to send the info.

Comment: How about let user select a row and then use popover (iPad) or pop up a small view with textbox.  After user typed in the text, just display (or not) it to the label on the cell.

Comment: You could have a textfield which appears only when the cell is in selected state.

Comment: My concern is with a textfield, if the user uses 255 characters there will not be enough space in a 200wide by 20high text field to display all the text. Is there some way to make it wrap and drop down to 2 or more lines to show the complete text in the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a UITextField in several different ways to make it not look out of place to you: things such as location, size, alignment, font, font size, background color, and etc.  You can have the text field appearance change depending on whether the text field is in the selected table row or not.

You can also have a UITextField delegate pre-check any changes to the text field, and prohibit entering a text length greater than some number of characters, or illegal/unwanted characters, etc.